# Vite / Vue3 Could not find a declaration file for module 'luxon'

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, luxon

I have a Laravel 10 - Vue3 project (using Docker).

I wanted to use Luxon package to manage datetime.
I installed the module in my project by

```
sail npm install --save luxon
```

when importing in my page component

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
```

it was giving me the error "Could not find a declaration file for module 'luxon'. 'path-to-module/luxon.js' implicitly has an 'any' type".

I also tried to install

```
sail npm i --save-dev @types/luxon
```

And finally also tried to add an index.d.ts under node_modules/luxon with the following content

```
declare module 'luxon';
```

Nothing of the previous operation solved my problem.

Any suggestion?

kind regards,
Matteo